# Azure Cosmos DB Graph Wildcard search

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Is it possible to search Vertex properties with a contains in Azure Cosmos Graph DB?

For example, I would like to find all persons which have `'Jr'` in their name?

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').has('name',within('Jr')).values('name')
```

Seems like the `within('')` function only filters values that are exactly equal to `'Jr'`. I am looking for a contains. **Ideally case insensitive.**

Comment: Normally with Tinkerpop / gremlin, you could do something like `g.V().hasLabel('person).filter{it.getProperty('name').toLowerCase().contains('jr')}.values('name')` but Cosmos DB Graph does not yet support closures.  Will respond to this thread once closures becomes available.

Comment: I was using textContains when using Titan but it looks like that's not available with Cosmos 
g.V().hasLabel('person').has('name',textContains('Jr'))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Azure team has now implemented [Tinkerpop predicates for String](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/)

The Azure team has "announced" this to [a user here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/36709345-string-operations-like-contains-and-startswith-sho) on their feedback website.

I haven't tested all of them, but containing works for me (it is case sensitive though)

```
g.V().hasLabel('doc').or(__.has('title', containing('truc')), __.has('tags', containing('truc')))
```

> TextP.startingWith(string)
>
> Does the incoming String start with the provided String?
>
> TextP.endingWith(string)
>
> Does the incoming String end with the provided String?
>
> TextP.containing(string)
>
> Does the incoming String contain the provided String?
>
> TextP.notStartingWith(string)
>
> Does the incoming String not start with the provided String?
>
> TextP.notEndingWith(string)
>
> Does the incoming String not end with the provided String?
>
> TextP.notContaining(string)
>
> Does the incoming String not contain the provided String?

Answer (score 5):

None of the text matching functions are available for CosmosDB at this time. However, I was able to implement a wildcard search functionality by using a UDF (User Defined Function) which uses the Javascript match() function:

```
function userDefinedFunction(input, pattern) { return input.match(pattern) !== null; };
```

Then you'd have to write your query as SQL and use the UDF that you defined (the example below assumes you called you function 'REGEX'

```
SELECT * FROM c where(udf.REGEX(c.name[0]._value, '.*Jr.*') and c.label='person')
```

The performance will be far from ideal so you need to decide if the solution is acceptable or not based on your latency and cost perspectives.

Comment: Hi from portal we can do this, but from Java SDK is this possible ?