# Azure Cosmos update June 2020 - Gremlin API - "containing" case insensitive?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

As of June 2020, Azure Cosmos DB supports **performant** case-insensitive searches for certain string functions like "contains". See [this MSFT dev-blogs link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/new-string-function-performance-improvements-and-case-insensitive-search/). This is great, because string-functions  usually kill the performance of "regular" databases.

My question: We are using the Gremlin-Graph-API and would urgently need this feature because a case-sensitive search kills the user-experience. Is there a way to do it?

Sample:

`g.V().has("name", containing("Fra"))` => `g.V().has("name", containing("Fra", <caseInsensitive=true>))`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can create a UDF as mentioned in the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864203/azure-cosmos-db-graph-wildcard-search) and then consume it as a sql query. However just check if it is feasible as per your requirements.

At the same time, I would recommend you to upvote the feature requested by a user on the same case-insensitive searches. More votes on it makes the product team prioritize the feature accordingly:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/41097427-gremlin-api-regex-and-case-insensitive-match

Comment: thanks, I will upvote the feature. the UDF is not a solution, because, as mentioned in my question, UDFs kill the performance. it causes a kind of full table search, however this is implemented in the respective data-store. so it would technically "work", but break our system.

Comment: Does anyone have any news on this? Thanks!